# How to solve problem installing Windows 7 onto RAID using Highpoint 2640x4:

Tags: windows-7, installation, raid

When installing Windows 7 64-bit to a 2-drive mirror RAID (2x1TB) using a Highpoint 2640x4 card, I encounter an error message (0x80300001) indicating that Windows cannot be installed to the detected drive (or any partitions thereon).

This is shortly after loading the raid drivers from the CD that came with the card.

What must be done to get Windows 7 installed on this raid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 installation doesn't prompt you to reinsert the Windows 7 installation DVD after loading the raid drivers.

You might get the error:

> Windows is unable to install to the selected location. Error: 0x80300001

As long as the raid driver disc is still in the drive.

**After your drive(s) appear in the destination list, replace the Windows 7 installation DVD and click Refresh.**

Help for this solution was found at [TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproinstall/thread/3021b3aa-ce05-4cfa-8119-a531ed2e4d63/).

Comment: Thank you. Such a misleading error message -- it makes you think something is wrong with the driver.